# Code not detecting empty input from user

Tags: java, exception, jdbc, sqlexception

I have a issue with the delete button. When I enter nothing in the text field and press the delete button I'm not getting a popup menu as an exception.

```
 private void billdeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        int id=Integer.parseInt(billidtext.getText());
        try (//step2 create  the connection object
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:xe","hr","****")) {
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "DELETE FROM bill " +
            "WHERE bid = ('"+id+"')";
            int w=stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            if(w!=0)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Deleted Successfully!"); //this is displayed successfully
            else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"value does not exists!");// this is displayed successfully
            supplieridtext.setText("");

            //view trigger
            String sql1="SELECT * FROM bill";

            stmt = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
            //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
            billtable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            rs.close();

            //step5 close the connection object
        }
    }catch( ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){ 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"no value entered!");}    //this line is not displayed when the text field is empty
}
```

Comment: It looks like you should also be catching a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` in case `Integer.parseInt` is given an input that it doesn't understand.

Comment: `billidtext.getText().trim().isEmpty()`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!billidtext.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
    // Do query
}
```

As already stated, you'll need to trap the `java.lang.NumberFormatException` for `int id=Integer.parseInt(billidtext.getText());` explicitly, as it's a "unchecked exception"

```
if (!billidtext.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
    try {
        int id=Integer.parseInt(billidtext.getText();
        // Do query
    } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException exp) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid value!");
    }
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"no value entered!");
}
```

You should also be making use of [`PreparedStatements`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)